# Sitemap Template

Tags: magento-enterprise, rwd

Hi I want to edit the Sitemap page on RWD theme of Magento.

Where can I locate that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable template hints from admin...and override the file file in your custom theme 
Check how to do it http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/

Comment: in what specific path?

Comment: Edited answer.....